# What is the .with() method for Map in Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

I came across the below code in a Groovy project:

```
payloadDetails?.with {
    payloadDetails.ardome.material_id = testAsset.materialId.trim()
    payloadDetails.ardome.itm_id = testAsset.itemId.trim()
    payloadDetails.ardome.mob_id = testAsset.mobId.trim()
    payloadDetails.ardome.min_id = testAsset.minId.trim()
    payloadDetails.ardome.original_ardome_filename = testAsset.originalFileName.trim()
}
```

where 'payloadDetails' variable is the return value of below (Map I assume):

```
static Map getCreateIndexPayload(String payloadName = 'CreateIndexPayload') {
     //some code
}
```

So `?` is the null safe operator, but what is the `.with()` method?

It looks like it's a method that allows reassigning Map's all or partial value member one by one. But I am not able to find this .with() definition in Map's interface document, or is it a method of Collection interface?

Is API documentation available for this method?

Answer (score 4):

[`Object#with`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#with(U,groovy.lang.Closure)) is a Groovy [extension method](https://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_extension_modules) that is available on any object. It takes a closure as a parameter and returns the closure's value. (For an equivalent that returns the original object, use `tap`; this is useful for nested initializations.)

In this case, the value of the closure (`testAsset.originalFileName.trim()`) is discarded, so the `with` simply has the effect of executing the closure against the object.

Note that the `with` and `tap` methods *delegate* to the target (that is, any assignments or method calls are resolved against it first), so the `payloadDetails` inside the closure is unnecessary and potentially a bug. Instead, you should be able to just say

```
payloadDetails?.with {
  ardome.material_id = testAsset.materialId.trim()
  ardome.itm_id = testAsset.itemId.trim()
  ardome.mob_id = testAsset.mobId.trim()
  ardome.min_id = testAsset.minId.trim()
  ardome.original_ardome_filename = testAsset.originalFileName.trim()
}
```

or, if `ardome` is a POJO and not a nested map*,

```
payloadDetails?.ardome?.with {
  material_id = testAsset.materialId.trim()
  itm_id = testAsset.itemId.trim()
  mob_id = testAsset.mobId.trim()
  min_id = testAsset.minId.trim()
  original_ardome_filename = testAsset.originalFileName.trim()
}
```

---

* or maybe if it is a nested map; you would need to try this yourself

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. when you say 'In this case, the value of the closure (testAsset.originalFileName.trim()) ', you mean 'the value of the closure of testAsset.materialId.trim(), testAsset.mobId.trim(), testAsset.minId.trim(), testAsset.originalFileName.trim()', not just the last trim(), right?

Comment: @user1559625 The value of a closure is its return value, which is implicitly the last expression if no `return` is used.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- you might want to add something about Spock's `with` as well, as that is a real thing https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_using_code_with_code_for_expectations

Comment: @LeonardBrünings Interesting, but that doesn't seem to be an actually distinct construct at the code level (though the Spock ASTT might make special provision for it); the semantics are identical, as those assertions are simply delegated onto the target.

Comment: You are missing the point, Spock's `with` enables implicit assertions on the delegate, which does not work when using the Groovy variant. You response is correct, for what the OP asked. However, the title and tags could lead other people here, that would expect information about Spock's version.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings I think I see the distinction you're making (which does in fact mean that it's an ASTT-replicated shadowing). Given that the OP's question ended up not involving Spock but just the core Groovy `with`, I'll remove the tag. (I appreciate the tip, though; I'd apparently missed when it was added in 1.2.)

Comment: @LeonardBrünings Thanks!